# вчера эта учётная запись будет удалена

Tags: дефект, локализация, инструменты-модератора

> [image: скриншот]

Надо что-то делать с этим сообщением:

> вчера эта учётная запись будет удалена; чтобы отменить удаление, нажмите сюда

1. Оно неверное.
2. Время, оставшееся до удаления, непонятно.
3. Оно криво сформулировано.

Аналогичная проблема с этим сообщением при другом времени:

> 22 часа назад эта учётная запись будет удалена; чтобы отменить удаление, нажмите сюда

Comment: Локализация тут не причём, имхо. Такое странное поведение со временем уже описывалось как-то на мете, если страницу не перезагружать долго.

Comment: @alexolut, страница была только открыта - сообщение изначально битое.

Comment: ну значит с датами какая-то шляпа. К переводам это отношение не имеет. Хотя запятую надо бы убрать, да.

Comment: @alexolut, лучше вообще всю вторую часть сделать ссылкой и изменить на "нажмите для отмены удаления".

Comment: Ничего вы не понимаете! Вот **[посмотрите это](https://youtu.be/r7Np704eOik)** и вам станет понятно почему там так написано! ;-)

Comment: То, что проблема лежит глубже строк в локализации, не означает, что это не дефект. [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано] следует убрать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а ответ написать?

Comment: @Qwertiy для этого нужно на MSE ещё спросить на всякий.

Comment: @D-side это либо [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано], либо [meta-tag:баг].

Comment: @Suvitruf а это не то же самое, что [meta-tag:дефект]? Если не это, то больше всего похоже на [meta-tag:статус-так-вышло].

Comment: @D-side синонимы.

Comment: @D-side надо бы на MSE найти вопрос. Если нету, задать новый.

Comment: [Спросил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331138/260198). Но, судя по всему, проще подогнать перевод.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу судить по реакции на [вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331138/260198), вряд ли они для этого случая сделают отдельную строку.

Предлагаю просто подправить перевод https://ru.traducir.win/string/88 на:

> Эта учётная запись запланирована на удаление $when$; чтобы отменить удаление, $linkStart$нажмите сюда$linkEnd$

В случае, если время ещё не истекло, будет:

> Эта учётная запись запланирована на удаление через 5 часов; чтобы отменить удаление, $linkStart$нажмите сюда$linkEnd$

Если время уже прошло, будет:

> Эта учётная запись запланирована на удаление 5 часов назад; чтобы отменить удаление, $linkStart$нажмите сюда$linkEnd$

Конечно, не совсем ясно запланировано ли 5 часов назад или само удаление должно было случиться 5 часов назад.

Если есть идеи, предложите другой вариант перевода в ответе.

Comment: Предложил, но не факт что лучше)

Answer (score 1):

> Эта учётная должна быть удалена $when$; чтобы отменить удаление, $linkStart$нажмите сюда$linkEnd$

Соответственно будет:

> Эта учётная должна быть удалена через 5 часов

> Эта учётная должна быть удалена 5 часов назад

Comment: Как-то "должна быть" и прошедшее время не очень сочетается.